# How to do a simple groupby in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry for this noob question. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'chemical': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'cost': [102, 104, 86, 20, 92], 'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
```

How can I get a ranked list of total cost by chemical?

I know it involves starting with this:

```
cost_by_chemical = df2.groupby('chemical')
```

but I'm not sure how to continue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC then you want the following:

```
In [18]:
df.groupby('chemical')['cost'].sum().rank().reset_index()

Out[18]:
  chemical  cost
0        A   2.0
1        B   1.0
```

Or

```
In [20]:    
df.groupby('chemical')['cost'].sum().reset_index()

Out[20]:
  chemical  cost
0        A   292
1        B   112
```